# Univac Math pack subroutines in old-school FORTRAN (pre-77)

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have been looking at an engineering paper [here](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1299&context=water_rep) which describes an old FORTRAN code for solving pipe flow equations (it's dated 1974, before FORTRAN was standardised as Fortran 77). On page 42 of this document the old code calls the following subroutine:

```
C SYSTEM SUBROUTINE FROM UNIVAC MATH-PACK TO
C SOLVE LINEAR SYSTEM OF EQ. 
CALL GJR(A,51,50,NP,NPP,$98,JC,V)
```

It's a bit of a long shot, but do any veterans or ancient code buffs recall this system subroutine and it's input arguments? I'm having trouble finding any information about it.

If I can adapt the old code my current application I may rewrite this in C++ or VBA, and will be looking for an equivalent function in these languages.

Comment: gjr is likely gauss jordan reduction. It cant be that hard to study the code and find an equivalent.

Comment: How does the standard matter at all here? It's a call to some library subroutine. Fortran 2008 can look exactly the same.

Comment: that `$98` is strange.. <non standard> alternate return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll add to this answer if I find anything more detailed, but I have a place to start looking for the arguments to `GJR`.

This function is part of the Sperry UNIVAC MATH-PACK library - a full list of functions in the library can be found in http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a170611.pdf `GJR` is described as "determinant; inverse; solution of simultaneous equations". Marginally helpful.

A better description comes from http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/74B/jresv74Bn4p251_A1b.pdf

> A FORTRAN subroutine, one of the Univac 1108 Math Pack programs,
>   available on the library tapes at the University of Maryland computing
>   center. It solves simultaneous equations, computes a determinant, or
>   inverts a matrix or any combination of the three above by using a
>   Gauss-Jordan elimination technique with column pivoting.

This is slightly more useful, but what we really want is "MATH-PACK, Programmer Reference", UP-7542 Rev. 1 from Sperry-UNIVAC (Unisys) I find a lot of references to this document but no full-text PDF of the document itself.

I'd take a look at the arguments in the function call, how they are set up and how the results are used, then look for equivalent routines in LAPACK or BLAS. See http://www.netlib.org/lapack/

I have a few books on piping networks including "Analysis of Flow in Pipe Networks" by Jeppson (same author as in the original PDF hosted by USU)  https://books.google.com/books/about/Analysis_of_flow_in_pipe_networks.html?id=peZSAAAAMAAJ - I'll see if I can dig that up. The book may have a more portable matrix solver than the proprietary Sperry-UNIVAC library.

#### Update:

From p. 41 of http://ngds.egi.utah.edu/files/GL04099/GL04099_1.pdf I found documentation for the `CGJR` function, the complex version of `GJR` from the same library. It is likely the only difference in the arguments is variable type (`COMPLEX` instead of `REAL`):

---

`CGJR` is a subroutine which solves simultaneous equations, computes a determinant, inverts a matrix, or does any combination of these three operations, by using a Gauss-Jordan elimination technique with column pivoting.

The procedure for using `CGJR` is as follows:

Calling statement: `CALL CGJR(A,NC,NR,N,MC,$K,JC,V)`

where

- `A` is the matrix whose inverse or determinant is to be determined. If simultaneous equations are solved, the last `MC-N` columns of the matrix are the constant vectors of the equations to be solved. On output, if the inverse is computed, it is stored in the first N columns of `A`. If simultaneous equations are solved, the last `MC-N` columns contain the solution vectors. `A` is a complex array.
- `NC` is an integer representing the maximum number of columns of the array `A`.
- `NR` is an integer representing the maximum number of rows of the array `A`.
- `N` is an integer representing the number of rows of the array `A` to be operated on.
- `MC` is the number of columns of the array `A`, representing the coefficient matrix if simultaneous equations are being solved; otherwise it is a dummy variable.
- `K` is a statement number in the calling program to which control is returned if an overflow or singularity is detected.
  1) If an overflow is detected, `JC(1)` is set to the negative of the last correctly completed row of the reduction and control is then returned to statement number `K` in the calling program.
  2) If a singularity is detected, `JC(1)`is set to the number of the last correctly completed row, and `V` is set to `(0.,0.)` if the determinant was to be computed. Control is then returned to statement number `K` in the calling program.
- `JC` is a one dimensional permutation array of `N` elements which is used for permuting the rows and columns of `A` if an inverse is being computed .. If an inverse is not computed, this array must have at least one cell for the error return identification. On output, `JC(1)` is `N` if control is returned normally.
- `V` is a complex variable. On input `REAL(V)` is the option indicator, set as follows:

  1. invert matrix
  2. compute determinant
  3. do 1. and 2.
  4. solve system of equations
  5. do 1. and 4.
  6. do 2. and 4.
  7. do 1., 2. and 4.

Notes on usage of row dimension arguments `N` and `NR`:

The arguments `N` and `NR` refer to the row dimensions of the `A` matrix.
`N` gives the number of rows operated on by the subroutine, while `NR`
refers to the total number of rows in the matrix as dimensioned by the
calling program. `NR` is used only in the dimension statement of the
subroutine. Through proper use of these parameters, the user may specify that only a submatrix, instead of the entire matrix, be operated on by the subroutine.

---

In your application (pipe flow), look at how matrix `A` and vector `V` are  populated before the call to `GJR` and how they are used after the call.

You may be able to replace the call to `GJR` with a call to LAPACK's `SGESV` or `DGESV` without much difficulty.

Aside: The Fortran community really needs a drop-in 'Rosetta library' that wraps LAPACK, *etc.* for replacing legacy/proprietary IBM, UNIVAC, and *Numerical Recipes* math functions. The perfect case would be that maintainers would replace legacy functions with *de facto* standard math functions but in the real world, many of these older programs are un(der)maintained and there simply isn't the will (or, as in this case, the ability) to update them.

#### Update 2:

I started work on a compatibility library for the Sperry MATH-PACK and STAT-PACK routines as well as a few other legacy libraries, posted at https://bitbucket.org/apthorpe/alfc

Further, I located my copy of Jeppson's *Analysis of Flow in Pipe Networks* which is a slightly more legible version of the PDF of *Steady Flow Analysis of Pipe Networks: An Instructional Manual* and modernized the codes listed in the text. I have posted those at https://bitbucket.org/apthorpe/jeppson_pipeflow

Note that I found a number of errors in both the code listings and in the example problems given for many of the codes. If you're trying to learn how to write a pipe flow solver based on Jeppson's paper or text, I'd strongly suggest reviewing my updated codes and test cases because they will save you hours of effort trying to understand why the code doesn't work and why you can't replicate the example cases. This took a fair amount of forensic computing to sort out.

#### Update 3:

The source to `CGJR` and `DGJR` can be found in http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a110089.pdf. `DGJR` is the closest to what you want, though it references more routines that aren't available (proprietary UNIVAC error-handling routines). It should be easy to convert `DGJR' to single precision and skip the proprietary calls. Otherwise, use the compatibility library mentioned above.